# Sumar horas a la fecha actual

Tags: javascript, funciones

estoy tratando de sumar 24 horas a la fecha actual en una función de Js, y que me devuelva la fecha con la suma de esas horas. Para ello estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
function sumarHoras(){

let fechaActual = new Date();
let horas = 24;

return fechaActual.setHours(fechaActual.getHours()+horas)
}
```

Pero no me está funcionando, agradecería su ayuda

Comment: Si entiendo bien, quieres sumarle un día a la fecha de hoy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer ya lo habías logrado, solo faltaba que ejecutes bien tu función. Podrías enviar como parámetro las horas, sería lo siguiente:

```js
function sumarHoras(horas) {
  let fechaActual = new Date();

  fechaActual.setHours(fechaActual.getHours() + horas);
  return fechaActual;
}

console.log(sumarHoras(24));
console.log(sumarHoras(0));
```

Comment: ay jaja, muy amable mil gracias